# Red Black Tree in C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, clrs

I am trying to implement red black tree in C. For reference I am using [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

But when I run the code I am getting  "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error message.

I can't figure out what's wrong in my code so, could anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?

The problem seems to be in the function `rb_insert_fixup()`, but I don't know what's wrong in it.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//constants
#define RED 0
#define BLACK 1

struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *parent;
    int color;
};

struct node *rb_insert(struct node *tree, struct node *z);

struct node *rb_insert_fixup(struct node *tree, struct node *z);

struct node *left_rotate(struct node *t, struct node *x);

struct node *right_rotate(struct node *t, struct node *x);

struct node *create_node(int key);

int main()
{
    struct node *tree = NULL;
    struct node *new;

    new = create_node(5);
    tree = rb_insert(tree, new);

    new = create_node(15);
    tree = rb_insert(tree, new);

    new = create_node(4);
    tree = rb_insert(tree, new);

    new = create_node(14);
    tree = rb_insert(tree, new);
    printf("inserting 14\n");

    printf("%d %d\n%d %d\n", (tree->left)->key, (tree->left)->color, ((tree->right)->left)->key, ((tree->right)->left)->color);

    return 0;
}

struct node *rb_insert_fixup(struct node *tree, struct node *z)
{
    struct node *y = NULL;

    printf("fixup \n");

    while ( z->parent != NULL && (z->parent)->color == RED )
    {
        printf("while\n");

        if ( (z->parent)->parent != NULL && printf("if condition %d\n", (((z->parent)->parent)->left)->color) && z->parent == ((z->parent)->parent)->left )
        {
            printf("start if\n");

            y = ((z->parent)->parent)->right;

            if ( y->color == RED )
            {
                (z->parent)->color = BLACK;
                y->color = BLACK;
                ((z->parent)->parent)->color = RED;
                z = (z->parent)->parent;
            }

            else if ( z == (z->parent)->right )
            {
                z = z->parent;
                tree = left_rotate(tree, z);
            }

            (z->parent)->color = BLACK;
            ((z->parent)->parent)->color = RED;
            tree = right_rotate(tree, ((z->parent)->parent));

            printf("End if\n");
        }

        else
        {
            y = ((z->parent)->parent)->left;

            if ( y->color == RED )
            {
                (z->parent)->color = BLACK;
                y->color = BLACK;
                ((z->parent)->parent)->color = RED;
                z = (z->parent)->parent;
            }

            else if ( z == (z->parent)->left )
            {
                z = z->parent;
                tree = right_rotate(tree, z);
            }

            (z->parent)->color = BLACK;
            ((z->parent)->parent)->color = RED;
            tree = left_rotate(tree, ((z->parent)->parent));

            printf("End else\n");
        }

        printf("End while\n");
    }

    tree->color = BLACK;

    return tree;
}

struct node *rb_insert(struct node *tree, struct node *z)
{
    struct node *y = NULL;
    struct node *x = tree;

    while (x != NULL)
    {
        y = x;

        if (z->key < x->key)
        {
            x = x->left;
        }

        else
        {
            x = x->right;
        }
    }

    z->parent = y;

    if (y == NULL)
    {
        tree = z;
    }

    else if (z->key < y->key)
    {
        y->left = z;
    }

    else
    {
        y->right = z;
    }

    z->left = NULL;
    z->right = NULL;
    z->color = RED;

    tree = rb_insert_fixup(tree, z);
    //printf("bye insert\n");

    return tree;
}

struct node *right_rotate(struct node *t, struct node *x)
{
    struct node *y = x->left;
    x->left = y->right;

    if (y->right != NULL)
    {
        (y->right)->parent = x;
    }

    y->parent = x->parent;

    if (x->parent == NULL)
    {
        t = y;
    }

    else if (x == (x->parent)->left)
    {
        (x->parent)->left = y;
    }

    else
    {
        (x->parent)->right = y;
    }

    y->right = x;
    x->parent = y;

    return t;
}

struct node *left_rotate(struct node *t, struct node *x)
{
    struct node *y = x->right;
    x->right = y->left;

    if (y->left != NULL)
    {
        (y->left)->parent = x;
    }

    y->parent = x->parent;

    if (x->parent == NULL)
    {
        t = y;
    }

    else if (x == (x->parent)->left)
    {
        (x->parent)->left = y;
    }

    else
    {
        (x->parent)->right = y;
    }

    y->left = x;
    x->parent = y;

    return t;
}

struct node *create_node(int key)
{
    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (new == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed to create a new node\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    else
    {
        new->key = key;
        new->left = NULL;
        new->right = NULL;
        new->parent = NULL;
        new->color = BLACK;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You have not returned a value with `create_node`. You need `return new;` at end of function.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings and treat them as errors. The problem BLUEPIXY pointed out, for example, *"main.c:260:1: Control may reach end of non-void function"*

Comment: 2) at `rb_insert_fixup` : `if ( (z->parent)->parent != NULL && ...){ ... } else { y = ((z->parent)->parent)->left;` : if-conditional-expression becomes false because `(z->parent)->parent ` is `NULL` and when else-block is executed,  `y = ((z->parent)->parent)->left;` might `y = NULL->left;` .. You check such `NULL` dereference.

Comment: There's nothing so wrong with your code that a good debugging session couldn't fix. I would look upon this as an opportunity to learn debugging. Debugging 101 should be a mandatory course at educational institutions.

Comment: What have you tried?  On what line is it crashing?

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me. Still getting error but I guess it is because I have not used sentinel node. As suggested by @paxdiablo I learnt basics of debugging (gdb) and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score -2):

I have written the code wrong. After writing it again from scratch (using CLRS) and including sentinal node this time, everything is fine.
The rb_delete_fixup() function is as follows. The changes are in inner if-else. Similarly we have to change the inner if-else of rb_insert_fixup. It was a blunder to not write the correct code from the pseudocode.

```
Node *rb_delete_fixup(Node *tree, Node *tree_nil, Node *x)
{


Node *w;

while ( x != tree && x->color == BLACK )
{
    if ( x == x->parent->left )
    {
        w = x->parent->right;

        if ( w->color == RED )
        {
            w->color = BLACK;
            x->parent->color = RED;
            tree = left_rotate(tree, tree_nil, x->parent);
            w = x->parent->right;
        }

        if ( w->left->color == BLACK && w->right->color == BLACK )
        {
            w->color = RED;
            x = x->parent;
        }

        else
        {
            if ( w->right->color == BLACK )
            {
                w->left->color = BLACK;
                w->color = RED;
                tree = right_rotate(tree, tree_nil, w);
                w = x->parent->right;
            }

            w->color = x->parent->color;
            x->parent->color = BLACK;
            w->right->color = BLACK;
            tree = left_rotate(tree, tree_nil, x->parent);
            x = tree;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        w = x->parent->left;

        if ( w->color == RED )
        {
            w->color = BLACK;
            x->parent->color = RED;
            tree = right_rotate(tree, tree_nil, x->parent);
            w = x->parent->left;
        }

        if ( w->left->color == BLACK && w->right->color == BLACK )
        {
            w->color = RED;
            x = x->parent;
        }

        else
        {
            if ( w->left->color == BLACK )
            {
                w->right->color = BLACK;
                w->color = RED;
                tree = left_rotate(tree, tree_nil, w);
                w = x->parent->left;
            }

            w->color = x->parent->color;
            x->parent->color = BLACK;
            w->left->color = BLACK;
            tree = right_rotate(tree, tree_nil, x->parent);
            x = tree;
        }
    }
}

x->color = BLACK;
}
```